# Why does tf.slice return this error?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to build a multi-layer perceptron wherein my data is made of pairs of traits, e.g. each input is an array `x_1 = [v_1,v_2]` where `v_i` are feature vectors. Therefore, my input tensor is of size `[None,2,50]` (each v_i is of size 50). Right now I'm trying and failing to split the input tensor into two tensors: one that will contain v_1's and one that will contain v_2's. For example, to get the v_1's modified tensor, I try:

```
v1 = tf.squeeze(tf.slice(input, [0,0,0], [-1, 1, -1]), squeeze_dims=[1]))
```

and I get: 
size must be of rank 3... It seems to me like it is.. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does `input.eval().shape` return? Have you tried the other methods, including `tf.unpack`?

Comment: It returns 'cannot evaluate tensor using eval() no default session is registered' :(

Comment: ok. do `sess=tf.InteractiveSession()` before.

Comment: I worked out some bugs and your answer from yesterday now works :). By the way, if I could bother you one final time, what do these lines do? My google-fu isn't strong enough..tf.concat(1, [a,b]).get_shape()
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(100)])

Comment: Why do you need to getShape and then TensorShape?

Comment: [tf.concat](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#concat) joins the two tensors over a given axis and `get_shape` was there to show you that the result indeed had the expected shape.

Comment: Thanks so much, you've really helped me a lot! :)

Comment: a small snippet reproducing the error would help.

Comment: I am able to do `input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,2,50])` and then `v1 = tf.squeeze(tf.slice(input, [0,0,0], [-1, 1, -1]), squeeze_dims=[1])`.

Answer (score 0):

split is on the  axis =1 (your 2nd dimension : [None,**2**,50]) and want equal distribution on both side : [1,1], (experiment with [2,0],[0,2] to see what happens , one the split won't get  anything)

```
v1,v2  = tf.split(input,num_or_size_splits=[1,1],axis=1)
v1 = tf.squeeze(v1,1)
```

split returns a list, squeeze might now work on it